# Stream music to Yamaha MusicCast devices

Tags: sound, streaming

is there a way to stream music from an Ubuntu device to a Yamaha MusicCast device (multi room audio system; speakers and AV receivers)? *MusicCast* seams to be a protocol but the devices also support *Airplay*.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using Gerbera which is available in the Software Center in 18.04 and is based on MediaTomb. Just install and run. I did have a problem with the UI on the first startup, but it was easily fixed by editing the config.xml for the app following directions [here](https://linoxide.com/tools/install-gerbera-ubuntu-16-04/) under the troubleshooting section at the end. My receiver is the Yamaha R-N602. Once everything is set up, you just click on Server in the MusicCast App to access your music that's on the server.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This works great. Now I just need a way to control the MusicCast speakers from my PC instead of walking to the next room and grabbing my phone. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

MediaTomb is mentioned  [ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2269867&s=f06ad8df2a10e1e240efc794e6808bea&p=13257512#post13257512) but I haven't used it.

If you know a programmer, you might be able to use the [API](http://habitech.s3.amazonaws.com/PDFs/YAM/MusicCast/Yamaha%20MusicCast%20HTTP%20simplified%20API%20for%20ControlSystems.pdf) but, again, I haven't used it.